# Overriding / Extending an MVC Controller / Area

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm currently working on an MVC project and I'm trying to figure out how I might go about extending the routes of an existing Controller within an Area, specifically from another project.

For instance, I have a Controller with an area that looks like the following :

```
namespace MyProject.Areas.Foo.Controllers
{
    [Authorize]
    public class FooController : ApplicationController
    {
          //code
    }
}
```

And what I would like to do, is be able to define another Controller, within a separate project that could extend this like so :

```
namespace MyOtherProject.Areas.Foo.Custom.Controllers
{
    public class FooController : ApplicationController
    {
          public string Bar()
          {
               return "Bar";
          }
    }
}
```

Basically, I would like the controllers to almost function as if I was using the `partial` keyword (so that I could call any of the actions in the original or the new one).

**The Main Problem**

What I am really trying to accomplish is that I have a main project with several areas and another area of my solution with various client folders. I want to be able to essentially extend the base controllers for my main project and add client-specific actions within these client folders so that they can be used in the main project. I'm already doing this with certain MVC Views, but I was hoping I could accomplish it with controllers as well.

**What I've tried**

- I tried using the `partial` keyword on both declarations of the class, but since they are in different projects / assemblies, I don't think that works.
- I defined a build event that would move the custom DLL into the `bin` directory of the main MVC project, but that didn't seem to work as expected.
- I've tried various approaches for inheritance, hoping the new class would get picked up, but those didn't work (received the duplicate controller declaration error).
- I've read about trying to use a custom `ControllerFactory` but I wasn't sure how to implement it.
- I've tried defining custom namespace routing parameters in the AreaRegistration section to pick up the new controller like the following example.

**Routing Example (AreaRegistration)**

```
context.MapRoute(
    AreaName,
    String.Format("{0}/{{action}}/{{id}}", AreaName),
    new { controller = AreaName, action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
    new[] { 
        String.Format("MyProject.Areas.{0}.Controllers", AreaName),
        String.Format("MyOtherProject.Areas.{0}.Custom.Controllers", AreaName)
    }
);
```

**Update**

I attempted an approach [seen here](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/2c83cb28ae8d452f63812fc44eee6dae) as per some of the comments discussion that involved simply handling this via inheritance :

```
// Main Project
namespace MyProject.Areas.Foo.Controllers
{
    [Authorize]
    public class FooController : ApplicationController
    {
          public ActionResult Index()
          {
              return View();
          }
    }
}

// This is in another project / namespace / assembly
namespace MyOtherProject.Foo.Controllers
{
    public class CustomFooController : MyProject.Areas.Foo.Controllers.FooController
    {
        [Route("Foo/Bar")]
        public string Bar()
        {
            return "Bar";
        }
    }
}
```

So my current steps are as follows :

- Inherited from the base `FooController` in the main project within another project / solution.
- Set up attribute routing to access the custom controller to avoid conflicting routes from the main project.
- Created a Build Event that moves the custom DLL into the main project when built (so it will be accessible) from the new custom project.

This didn't seem to make any difference. I tried going to the `Foo/Bar` url but it just threw a 404 as if it didn't see it at all. The `CustomFooController.cs` file is in it's own separate project and is just a class file and not an MVC project. Is this correct? Do I need to set the routing rules in the main project?

Comment: What's wrong with using inheritance?  In project-B, include a reference to project-main, then controller-B inherit from controller-main.   Alternatively, use a common class as the base and configure your routes accordingly.

Comment: So I should inherit my Project B Controller from `FooController` in Project A? If so, how would this affect my routing as I want to be able to use the same basic routing i.e. `Foo/ProjectAAction` or `Foo/ProjectBAction`. Would that still work?

Comment: All routes to controller-B would also get controller-main actions because they are part of controller-B by inheritance. ie your routes would not know about project-main controllers

Comment: I would just use attribute routing here. Your chief problem is trying to force controller and action names in order to fit into the default `/controller/action` routing convention. With attribute routing, you can make the routes whatever the heck you want, and the controller/action names no longer matter.

Comment: Thanks Chris. Would inheritance alone be enough? I tried to use an approach like [this Gist](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/2c83cb28ae8d452f63812fc44eee6dae), but I don't know if that would be enough? I'm using a build event to place that custom Project-B DLL into the appropriate directory when building, so I should be able to go to `Foo/Bar` to access it right? And `Foo/Index` and everything else from the first one should work?

Comment: As a follow up, I tried using the code I provided in the Gist, however it doesn't seem like it recognized anything. I couldn't seem to navigate to `Foo/Bar`, but everything in the default `FooController` seemed to work as expected. Would the fact that `FooController` is in an area cause issues with this?

Comment: Why use inheritance? attribute routing is enough. https://gist.github.com/pomarc/22fdfca610c944ae09f57ef60750ade4

Answer (score 7):

**Controller Inheritance**

Using inheritance as [Chris](https://stackoverflow.com/users/654031/chris-pratt) mentioned in the comments section will likely be the best way of going about this as well. This is especially true if you are already deriving from another base controller class like `ApplicationController` in your example :

```
// ProjectA is assumed to be your "main" MVC application
public class CustomFooController :  ProjectA.Controllers.FooController
{
    [Route("Foo/Bar")]
    public ActionResult Bar()
    {
        return Content("Bar");
    }
}
```

The attribute routing here is extremely important as you don't want your existing routes to confuse your two controllers or overlook them.

**Registering Attribute Routes**

Since you are using attribute routing via the `[Route]` attribute within your ProjectB section, you'll want to ensure that you explicitly set it within the `RouteConfig.cs` of your ProjectA project so that it can properly identify it through the `Routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes()` method as seen below :

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    // This is important to set up your Route Attributes
    routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();

    // Route declarations omitted for brevity
}
```

Likewise, if you are using Areas, you'll want to configure this within the respective `AreaRegistration.cs` file as well :

```
public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context) 
{
    // Wire up any attribute based routing
    context.Routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();

    // Area routing omitted for brevity
}
```

**Scoping Routes**

Finally, the last thing you'll want to make sure to do is properly "scope" your routes to prioritize your main namespace within the `RouteConfig.cs` of your main ProjectA application :

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
    routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();
    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Default",
        url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Foo", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
        // This will prioritize your existing Controllers so they work as expected  
        namespaces: new[] { "ProjectA.Controllers"}
    );
}
```

**Getting References Across**

You mentioned using a Build Event to copy over the DLL from your ProjectB project into your main ProjectA project, which should be fine in this case. You will basically need *some* way to access it and a simply `xcopy` like the following should be fine in most scenarios :

```
xcopy /E /Y /S  "$(ProjectName).dll" "$(SolutionDir)\ProjectA\Bin\"
```

**Putting It All Together**

If you have wired up all of these steps correctly, you should be able to Clean / Rebuild your existing solution. After doing so, double-check to ensure that you have the appropriate DLL within your ProjectA `bin` directory :

[image]

If that is there, then you are on the right track and should be able to run your main application and navigate to `~/Foo` to see the following :

[image]

Likewise, navigating to `~/Foo/Bar` should pick up the appropriate attribute route that was defined in your other Controller and serve the proper content :

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! This worked exactly like I had imagined. Thanks for understanding what I was trying to do!