# Why does the compiler not find my controller extension in ASP.NET Core 3.1 MVC?

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc

I have created the following controller extension method:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using System;

namespace CodeResource.ApplicationShared.Extensions
{
    public static class ControllerExtensions
    {
        public static string GetSemanticName([NotNull] this Controller myController)
        {
            Guard.NotNull(myController, nameof(myController));

            var controllerFullName = nameof(myController);

            var controllerName = controllerFullName.Remove(
                controllerFullName.LastIndexOf(
                    "Controller",
                    StringComparison.Ordinal));

            return controllerName;
        }
    }
}
```

However, when I call it from one of my controllers, as follows, the compiler tells me that the method does not exist:

```
using CodeResource.ApplicationShared.Extensions;

var semanticName = SearchResultsController.GetSemanticName();
```

Any ideas as to why this isn't working?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37658902/overriding-extending-an-mvc-controller-area

Comment: Can you call it via `var semanticName = CodeResource.ApplicationShared.Extensions.GetSemanticName(SearchResultsController);` ?